# Neo4J: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.refactor.mergeNodes`

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have Officer nodes belonging to the same community (property community_probably_same_officer that I created with Graph Data Science). I would like to merge those nodes with apoc.refactor.mergeNodes.
I cannot use the iterate apoc since it has a bug that I reported so this is a workaround.

I wrote this code:

```
match (n:Officer)
with collect(distinct n.community_probably_same_officer) as idcom
unwind idcom as unwidcom
MATCH (n:Officer) where n.community_probably_same_officer=unwidcom
WITH unwidcom, collect(n) AS nodicom
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(nodicom,{
properties:"discard", mergeRels:true, preserveExistingSelfRels:false})
yield node
return count(*)
```

and I have this error

Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.refactor.mergeNodes`: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Throwable.getMessage()" because the return value of "org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException.getCause()" is null

When I used this code for other communities based on a different property it worked with no problems.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give us sample data to work on? Thanks

Comment: I'm working on Panama Papers data

Comment: BTW: Your first 5 lines of Cypher can be simplified to: `MATCH (n:Officer) WITH n.community_probably_same_officer AS unwidcom, COLLECT(n) AS nodicom`.

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with your use of the APOC procedure. For example, it should not be possible for `nodicom` to contain any `NULL` values. You may want to submit an [issue](https://github.com/neo4j/apoc/issues) for this.